# VBA Vlookup inside For loop not working

Tags: vba

```
For i = 2 To countSeca  
totalSeca = totalSeca + Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & (i + 6)).Value, rngSeca, 2, False)  
Next i
```

My code works perfectly, if on the Vlookup I put for example the number 5065544, but do not work if I put "5065544", the same for my controls, even when them contain the number 5065544. I think, is a problem of text format, and to fix it, I have tried, CInt, Int, CLng, Val(), among others, just before the control, but still doesn't work.

I was able to fix it. Function Int works fine. Seems my mistake.

Comment: What error message are you getting? And are you sure the lookup value is present? You will get an error value if not found which you won't be able to add to. And did you try UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & (i + 6)).Value * 1 ? What is the value of UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & (i + 6)).Value when it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write these before the loop to see whether there is some value on the `UserForm1.Controls` and whether you are getting it exactly:

```
MsgBox UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & (2 + 6)).Value
MsgBox UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & (3 + 6)).Value
MsgBox UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & (4 + 6)).Value
MsgBox UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & (5 + 6)).Value
MsgBox rngSeca.Address & rngSeca.Parent.Name
```

The last line shows the address of the `rngSeca` and its worksheet name.